# PL/SQL Trigger Variable Problems

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am relatively new to PL/SQL and i am trying to create a trigger that will alert me after an UPDATE on a table Review. When it is updated I want to ge the username(User table), score(Review Table), and product name (Product Table) and print them out:

This is what I have so far:

three tables:

```
Review: score, userid,pid, rid
Users: userid,uname
Product: pid,pname
```

So Review can reference the other tables with forigen keys.

```
    create or replace trigger userNameTrigger


    after insert on review
    for each row

    declare


    x varchar(256);
    y varchar(256);
    z varchar(256);


    begin


    select uname into x , pname into y  , score into z
from review r , product p , users u
where r.pid = p.pid and r.userid = u.userid and r.rid =new.rid;




    dbms_output.put_line('user: '|| X||'entered a new review for Product: '|| Y || 'with a review score of: '|| Z);


    end;
```

The problem I am having is I cannot seem to figure out how to store the selected fields into the variables and output it correctly.

DDL:

```
    Create Table Review
    (
        score    varchar2(100)
      , userid   varchar2(100)   
      , pid      varchar2(100) 
      , rid      varchar2(100) 
    );

Create Table Users
(
    userid   varchar2(100)
  , uname    varchar2(100)
);

Create Table Product
(
    pid      varchar2(100)
  , pname    varchar2(100)
);
```

Comment: Using dbms_output means only the user doing the insert will see the message - and then only if they've enabled output - which is a bit pointless. It's only really useful/safe for debugging. You'll also always get one or more rows, so not sure what the point of the query is; and you're likely to hit a mutating table error as you are querying the table the trigger is against - though that doesn't appear to be neccesary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem I can see is that you're missing a colon when you refer to `new.rid`. The second is that you're accessing the review table inside a row-level trigger on that same table, which will give you a mutating table error at some point; but you don't need to as all the data from the inserted row is in the `new` pseudorow.

```
create or replace trigger userNameTrigger
after insert on review
for each row
declare
  l_uname users.uname%type;
  l_pname product.pname%type;
begin
  select u.uname into l_uname
  from users u
  where u.userid = :new.userid;

  select p.pname
  into l_pname
  from product
  where p.pid = :new.pid;

  dbms_output.put_line('user '|| l_uname
    || ' entered a new review for product ' || l_pname
    || ' with a review score of '|| :new.score);
end;
```

The bigger problem is that the only person who could see the message is the user inserting tow row, which seems a bit pointless; and they would have to have output enabled in their session to see it.

If you're trying to log that so someone else can see it then store it in a table or write it to a file. As the review table can be queried anyway it seems a bit redundant though.

Having all your table columns as strings is also not good - don't store numeric values (e.g. scores, and probably the ID fields) or dates as strings, use the correct data types. It will save you a lot of pain later. You also don't seem to have any referential integrity (primary/foreign key) constraints - so you can review a product that doesn't exist, for instance, which will cause a no-data-found exception in the trigger.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the advice!

Answer (score 2):

It makes really no sense to use a trigger to notify themselves about changed rows. If you insert new rows into the table, then you have all info about them. Why not something like the block below instead a  trigger:

```
create table reviews as select 0 as rid, 0 as userid, 0 as score, 0 as pid from dual where 1=0;
create table users as select 101 as userid, cast('nobody' as varchar2(100)) as uname from dual;
create table products as select 1001 as pid, cast('prod 1001' as varchar2(100)) as pname from dual;

<<my>>declare newreview reviews%rowtype; uname users.uname%type; pname products.pname%type; begin 
    insert into reviews values(1,101,10,1001) returning rid,userid,score,pid into newreview;
    select uname, pname into my.uname, my.pname
    from users u natural join products p
    where  u.userid = newreview.userid and p.pid = newreview.pid
    ;
    dbms_output.put_line('user: '||my.uname||' entered a new review for Product: '||my.pname||' with a review score of: '||newreview.score);
end;
/
```

output: `user: nobody entered a new review for Product: prod 1001 with a review score of: 10`

In order to inform another session about an event you should use dbms_alert (transactional) or dbms_pipe (non transactional) packages. An example of dbms_alert:

```
create or replace trigger new_review_trig after insert on reviews for each row
begin
    dbms_alert.signal('new_review_alert', 'signal on last rid='||:new.rid); 
end;
/
```

Run the following block in another session (new window, worksheet, sqlplus or whatever else). It will be blocked until the registered signal is arrived:

```
<<observer>>declare message varchar2(400); status integer; uname users.uname%type; pname products.pname%type; score reviews.score%type;
begin
    dbms_alert.register('new_review_alert');
    dbms_alert.waitone('new_review_alert', observer.message, observer.status); 
    if status != 0 then raise_application_error(-20001, 'observer: wait on new_review_alert error'); end if;
    select uname, pname, score into observer.uname, observer.pname, observer.score
    from reviews join users using(userid) join products using (pid)
    where rid = regexp_substr(observer.message, '\w+\s?rid=(\d+)', 1,1,null,1) 
    ;
    dbms_output.put_line('observer: new_review_alert for user='||observer.uname||',product='||observer.pname||': score='||observer.score);
end;
/
```

Now in your session:

```
insert into reviews values(2, 101,7,1001);
commit; --no alerting before commit
```

The another (observer) session will be finished with the output: 
`observer: new_review_alert for user=nobody,product=prod 1001: score=7`

Answer (score 0):

P.S. There was no RID in the Table REVIEW, so i'll just assume it was supposed to be PID.

```
create or replace trigger userNameTrigger
after insert on review
for each row
declare

    x varchar2(256);
    y varchar2(256);
    z varchar2(256);

BEGIN

    select  uname 
          , pname
          , score
    INTO    x
          , y
          , z
    from   review r 
        ,  product p 
        ,  users u
    where  r.pid = p.pid 
    and    r.userid = u.userid 
    and    r.PID = :new.pid;
    dbms_output.put_line('user: '|| X ||'entered a new review for Product: '|| Y || 'with a review score of: '|| Z);

end userNameTrigger;
```

You just made a mistake on the INTO statement, you can just clump them together in one INTO.

Comment: ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Comment: The problem is I cannot figure out how to record when a new user updates the Review Table